# Ramsey Number on R3

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, upper-lower-bounds, ramsey-theory

Let R(s,s,s) be the smallest integer n such that every 3-coloring of the edges of Kn contains a monochromatic Ks.

1) show R(s,s,s) ≤ 27^s

2) calculate an exponential lower bound for R(s,s,s), which grows exponentially with s.

For 1) I derived that $R(s,s,s) < R (s,R(s,s)) = R(s, \binom{2s-2}{s-1})$ I dont really know how to derive the 27^s result.

for 2) any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess it should be $R (s,R(s,s))\le R\left(s, \binom{2s-2}{s-1}\right)$ instead.